# Retrieve Most Recent Activity in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good Day

I have a table of Activities that occurred in different dates and can be retrieved with the query (T-SQL) bellow:

```
Select  Activities.activityid,
        Activities.ActivityTypeCode,
        Activities.ActivityDate,
        Activities.SequenceOrder,
        Activities.Place,
        Activities.TypeOfPlace
From Activities
Where Activities.ActivityTypeCode In ('LOST', 'FOUND', 'NOT SEEN')
```

Queston: How can I retrieve the most recent one? or the second most recent?

For your info: There is a certain field called sequenceOrder that tracks the sequence when the activities are being entered.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: i am using MS SQL

Comment: if I'm not misunderstanding you i think you can use`order by Activities.ActivityDate desc` and most recent one `select top 1`

Comment: Do you want the most recent FOR lost and found and not seen? ie 3 results or the most recent OF lost,found,not seen ie 1 result

Comment: The most recent of any of them

Comment: i want one of them which is most recent

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` clause with *sub-query*

```
SELECT * 
FROM Activities
WHERE sequenceOrder IN (
              SELECT MAX(SequenceOrder) 
              FROM Activities
              WHERE ActivityTypeCode In ('LOST', 'FOUND', 'NOT SEEN')
              GROUP BY ActivityTypeCode 
)
```

If, you want to get the only top most activity among one of (*LOST*, *FOUND*, *NOT SEEN)* then remove `GROUP BY`  clause from *sub-query*.

Comment: @jarlh... not sure but the statement says i have sequenceOrder that tracks the sequence when the activities are being entered.

Comment: If they aren't, your query will return more or less all rows.

Comment: yes the sequence order values are unique, they are entered by the system as I am entering the details of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    activityid,
    ActivityTypeCode,
    ActivityDate,
    SequenceOrder,
    Place,
    TypeOfPlace
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SequenceOrder DESC) rn
    FROM Activities
    WHERE ActivityTypeCode IN ('LOST', 'FOUND', 'NOT SEEN')
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The advantage of this approach is that if you want the second most recent event, we can use `WHERE rn = 2`.

Note that if there could be ties for values in the sequence order, then we might want to use a rank function instead of row number.

You may place the above query into a CTE (common table expression):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        activityid,
        ActivityTypeCode,
        ActivityDate,
        SequenceOrder,
        Place,
        TypeOfPlace
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SequenceOrder DESC) rn
        FROM Activities
        WHERE ActivityTypeCode IN ('LOST', 'FOUND', 'NOT SEEN')
    ) t
    WHERE rn = 1
)

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

But note that wrapping a query in a subquery is not desirable from a performance point of view.  Instead, just tailor my original query to fit your needs.

Comment: this one work, but can I put as a derived table inside another query I am working on?

Comment: the reason is that there are still some other conditions that I need to satisfy that are outside the Activities table

Comment: to make it clear, can I take that query and put it into a derived table and refer to it by an alias?

Comment: @RabelaniNetshifhire Yes, you may put my query into a CTE or temp/derived table.  Not sure exactly what you have in mind.

Comment: please show me how to do that, sorry, coz when I do it, it say the fields cannot be bound

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
Select  Activities.activityid,
    Activities.ActivityTypeCode,
    Activities.ActivityDate,
    Activities.SequenceOrder,
    Activities.Place,
    Activities.TypeOfPlace,
    row_number() over (partition by Activities.ActivityTypeCode order by Activities.SequenceOrder) [rn]
From Activities
Where Activities.ActivityTypeCode In ('LOST', 'FOUND', 'NOT SEEN')
) a where rn = 1 --2 if you want second most recent
```

Comment: Your outer `select *` will also select the row number.